# Vuetify v-card fit all height possible in v-col

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm building a login/signup page with vue and vuetify.
I put the code below (the text is in italian bc i am italian but you can get the point):

```
<v-row 
      align="center"
      justify="center"
      class="prova"
    >
        <v-col
        cols="10"
        lg="3"
        md="4"
        sm="5"
        >
          <v-card
          >
            <v-card-title class="center">
              Login
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text
              class="center"
            >
              <v-container>
                <v-form>
                  <v-text-field
                    label="Email"
                    required
                  ></v-text-field>

                  <v-text-field
                    :append-icon="showPassword ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
                    :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
                    label="Password"
                    counter
                    @click:append="showPassword = !showPassword"
                  ></v-text-field>

                  <v-btn
                    color="primary"
                  >
                    Accedi
                  </v-btn>
                </v-form>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
        <v-col
        cols="10"
        lg="3"
        md="4"
        sm="5"
        fill-height
        >
          <v-card
          >
            <v-card-title class="center">
              Registrazione
            </v-card-title>

            <v-card-text class="center">
            <v-container >
              <div
              >Vuoi accedere al sito 
                ma non sei registrato? 
                Clicca qui sotto 
                per farlo subito!</div>
              <br>
              <v-btn
                color="primary"
              >
                Registrati
              </v-btn>
            </v-container>
            </v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

If you try this as you will see the "Registrati" (sign up) card has a lower height than the Login card. Is there a way (with css preferably but if no way with js) to make the height the same as the login card so that they look better?

Thanks! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this codesandbox I made: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-70836234-11sck?file=/src/components/CardHeight.vue

Remove `align="center"` from your `v-row`. Then just add the css `height:100%` to your `v-card`

**UPDATE:**
To set a fixed height to `v-card` only on mobile view you, can use [vuetify's display breakpoints](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/breakpoints/), in this case I applied them to the `style` attribute, but you can use it with any html attribute and any place with js.

```html
<!-- Card 1 -->
<v-card :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly ? 'height: 280px' : ''">
...
</v-card>

<!-- Card 2 -->
<v-card :style="$vuetify.breakpoint.xsOnly ? 'height: 280px' : 'height:100%'">
...
</v-card>
```

[image]

Comment: if i try the mobile view the button overflow and the height isn't the same. Do you have an idea on how i can fix this too? Thanks! Have a nice day!

Comment: Sure, you can use vuetify's display breakpoints to set an specific css on xs (mobile) view. I updated my answer and codesandbox.

Comment: ok, but can i just use the same height i have on pc on mobile? Bc i'd like to keep things the same! Thanks

Comment: In that case you don't need to use breakpoints. Does this pc height comes from the class `prova`?

Comment: No, maybe i did't explained me well. On pc everything works fine but when i try the mobile view the second box (the one which we put the same height as the first one) stretches itself. I try posting a picture here in minutes so you can see.

Comment: Here it is the example: https://imgur.com/a/AELFe1S

Comment: Got you, looks like the code sanbox didn't update with I added the vuetify breakpoints, check it again. It should work now.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my issue

Comment: I'm glad to help!, if you find my answer useful. Please consider mark the answer as accepted.